# Speed up matrix calculations with for loop

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have the following code.

```
bigImage = zeros(2809,1024);
for a = 0:52
    for b = 0:52
        image2 = image1((a*8+1):(a*8+64), (b*8+1):(b*8+64));
        % here do something with image2 and get a (1x1024) vecotr A
        count = (a * 53) + (b + 1);
        bigImage(count,:) = A;
    end
end
```

I want to reduce the time this loop takes. 
Are there any suggestions what I can do?

Comment: The answer may depend on what you do to `image2` to obtain `A`. Can you be more specific?

Comment: i calculate a gray level features of image2 which gives a 1x1024 vector. I have optimized the feature calculation part. It has an execution time of 0.002 seconds.

Comment: Look into `im2col` with `distinct` option that will give you those blocks as columns of a 2D matrix. Then, see if you can make the gray level feature calculating function work on all those columns in one go. So, if that works you would have a `nx1024` matrix output for n columns. In your case, `n` would be `53x53`.

Comment: sorry Divakar..I don't understand how to do like that? Could you please explain more?

Comment: Do this - `im2col(image1,[64 64],'sliding')`, you would have `NxM` matrix, where M would be `64*64`. From that you need to choose certain columns that correspond to the sliding stepsize of `8`. So you would have a reduced `N1xM` matrix. Now, you need to see if your gray level feature calculating function could work on this new matrix and produce `N1x1024` sized ouput array.

Comment: thanks divakar..now I understood. I will try